# Converting MD5 result into an integer in C

Tags: c, casting, md5

My goal is to use the result of an MD5 result to index a hash table. I want to perform a Modulo operation on it to find the appropriate slot in the table. I have tried casting it as an unsigned long long type. When I printed the result, I got a different number every time for the same MD5 hash. The MD5 hash is initially an unsigned char *. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my function:

```
int get_fp_slot(unsigned char * fingerprint, int size)
{
return (unsigned long long)fingerprint % size;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to cast a pointer, which doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: What is 'fingerprint' ? A pointer to the string representation of the hash value? I suggest you build an integer representation of the string representation of the hash value, and retry. In the above code, you are using the pointer, as opposed to the actual value of the hash. Not quite what you are trying to achieve. Also, be aware of the possibilities of collision since you are trying to compress the key here.

Comment: You should consider using a hashing algorithm besides md5 to make collisions less likely.

Comment: @C0deH4cker - But MD5 _is_ a hashing algorithm!

Comment: I said *besides* md5. Meaning one whose output is smaller so you dont need to compress it.

Comment: Fingerprint is a pointer to the string representation of the hash. Collisions are not a big deal for what I am doing. @OliCharlesworth You were correct. I was casting the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MD5 hash is a 128 bit number. So for best performance you should probably keep all 128 bits.

Given that your function takes the 128 bit hash as a character string, you need to parse that string into a series of 4 integers. Your string probably looks something like this:

```
79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4
```

That is a 32 byte hexadecimal string. If so, you extract the binary version like this:

```
int v1, v2, v3, v4;
sscanf( &fingerprint[0], "%x", &v1 );
sscanf( &fingerprint[8], "%x", &v2 );
sscanf( &fingerprint[16], "%x", &v3 );
sscanf( &fingerprint[24], "%x", &v4 );
```

What you do now really depends on how good you want your hash to be. If you really need to use a 32 bit number then just XOR all those numbers together:

```
int hash = v1 ^ v2 ^ v3 ^v4;
```

Comment: So for v1, sscanf would take the as much from fingerprint that could fit in the int right? But wouldn't that be the first 4 bytes only? Why is the MD5 itself 16 bytes, but prints a 32 byte hex value?

Comment: sscanf will parse as many bytes as it can, in this case 8. You could copy out 8 bytes at a time into a temp buffer if that feels safer to you (e.g. to protect against a broken sscanf ).Each character encodes just 4 bits 1/2 byte. The char itself is 8-bits, but in this case it encodes just 4 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the pointer, i.e. the *address* of the hash. Of course that address is unrelated to the value of the hash.

How to fix it depends on what you want. You can for example use the last 16 bytes of the hash and parse that to an `unsigned long long`,

```
// sanity and error checking omitted for brevity
int get_fp_slot(unsigned char *fingerprint, int size)
{
    size_t len = strlen(fingerprint);
    size_t offset = len < 16 ? 0 : len-16;
    unsigned long long hash_tail = strtoull(fingerprint + offset,NULL,16);
    return hash_tail % size;
}
```

or do the modulo incrementally

```
// uses a helper hex_val that converts a hexadecimal digit to the integer it signifies
int get_fp_slot(unsigned char *fingerprint, int size)
{
    unsigned long long hash_mod = 0;
    while(*fingerprint) {
        hash_mod = (16*hash_mod + hex_val(*fingerprint)) % size;
        ++fingerprint;
    }
    return hash_mod;
}
```

Comment: In the second solution, when does the while loop end?

Comment: At the 0-terminator, I just forgot the increment :(

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are converting the pointer itself, not the bytes that form the MD5 value!

A MD5 is 128 bits, that is 16 bytes. Assuming that your `long long` type is 64 bits (8 bytes) you can represent it as two `long long` values, then XOR them to get the hash. Or if you prefer, you could simply pick one of them... the hash quality is probably similar.

You don't say it, but I'm assuming that your fingerprint is a pointer to an array of 16 bytes with the MD5 value. Then:

```
unsigned long long a = *(unsigned long long*)fingerprint;
unsigned long long b = *(unsigned long long*)(fingerprint + 8);
return a ^ b;
```

Note that the values of `a` and `b` will depend on the endianness of your machine. It doesn't matter as long as you don't send the hashes to a different architecture.

Comment: whoa - this is probably wrong though. The character buffer is probably a textual representation of the hash - not an actual hash. Your hash function will end up sparse. E.g. there are lots of bits that will always be zero if you do this.

Comment: So the actual hash is a number? Also, as far the results of this operation, wrong as it may be, the numbers I am getting from any individual hash are consistent. Nevertheless, I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista - I don't know why you think the textual representation is more likely. A quick check at `man MD5_Final` for example says that it returns 16 bytes, that is a binary representation of the hash. Naturally, the OP doesn't say which library he is using, so we are only guessing...

Comment: You're right, we don't know. But the prototype char* suggests text.

Comment: I'm using the cypto Api in the linux kernel. It asks for a unsigned char buffer to place the result in.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista - Actually, a `char*` would suggest text; an `unsigned char *` suggests raw binary.