# C sscanf MD5 to integer not working

Tags: c, md5, scanf

I have a function that transforms strings into MD5:

```
if(snprintf(target, 7, "123456") == -1){
    errx(1, "snprintf");            
}

uint a[4];
char w[64] = {0};

strncpy(w, target, 56);

md5_prep(w);
md5_cpu((uint*)&w[0], &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3]);

printf("%llu %llu %llu %llu\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
```

This printf gives me:

```
970722017 2874784329 1474320062 1049104370
```

I know it is correct because if I convert it to HEX it is fine, if instead the password I have the MD5 hash on and try to do this:

```
if(snprintf(g, 33, "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e") == -1){
    errx(1, "snprintf");            
}

uint a[4];

sscanf(&g[0], "%x", &a0]);
sscanf(&g[8], "%x", &a[1]); 
sscanf(&g[16], "%x", &a[2]);
sscanf(&g[24], "%x", &a[3]);

printf("%llu %llu %llu %llu\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
```

The result is:

```
4294967295 4294967295 4061104190 4061104190
```

Shouldn't both printfs be equal?

I tool this MD5 to int conversion through sscanf from this thread:
[Converting MD5 result into an integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180028/converting-md5-result-into-an-integer-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is endian order. 970722017 in hex is 39dc0ae1 not e10adc39. The different is the order of the 4 bytes. A 4 byte integer can either have the least significant byte first,  or other most significant byte first, it depends on the system you are running on.

In other words your arrangement of bytes in a 4byte int is backward when compared to a sequential string of bytes.

Depending on what you are doing, your md5 is actually: 39dc0ae1ab59ba4957e056de3e880ff2

Comment: Yes you were right, I manually solved this endian order with some bit shifting.